# Could not find table error in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a rails app set up with a many-to-many relationship between `users` and `widgets`. "Users" has been generated and managed through the `devise` gem. When I click on create new widget, when logged in as a user, I get the error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in WidgetsController#create
>
> Could not find table 'users_widgets'

My migration files are as follows:

```
class CreateWidgets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
        create_table :widgets do |t|
            t.string :name
            t.timestamps null: false
        end
    end
    create_table :users_widgets, id: false do |t|
        t.belongs_to :user, index: true
        t.belongs_to :widget, index: true
    end
end

class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""
      #other devise stuff...
  end
end
```

and my `widget_controller`:

```
  def create
    @user = current_user
    @widget = @user.widgets.build(widget_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @widget.save
        format.html { redirect_to @widget, notice: 'Widget was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @widget }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @widget.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

What have I done wrong / what is causing this error? I would have thought the definition in the createWidgets class was enough?

## Update:

I hve changed my create_widgets migration file to this:

```
class CreateWidgets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :widgets do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    create_table :users_widgets, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.belongs_to :widget, index: true
    end
  end    
end
```

and run:

```
$rake db:reset
$rake db:migrate
```

but I still get the same error...

Comment: Did you actually run your migrations?

Comment: @jvillian Yes, however, please see my comment on the other question, as I am struggling to re-migrate the tables...

Comment: To start fresh, do rake db:reset **or** rake db:drop; rake db:create; rake db:migrate; rake db:test:prepare

Comment: The more aggressive approach is rake db:drop, etc . Did you try that?

Comment: @jvillian Thanks - that did it!

Comment: Great to hear! If my answer was the correct one, can you please mark it as such so future readers can find it?

Comment: @jvillian Well, the answer marked actually fixed the problem with the migrations, yours was just necessary to force the change with the database, you can have my upvotes though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your `CreateWidgets` migration as follows:

```
class CreateWidgets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :widgets do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    create_table :users_widgets, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.belongs_to :widget, index: true
    end
  end    
end
```

Both `create_table` statements have to go with in `change`, not outside.

Also did you add the `create_table` for `users_widgets` before or after running the `CreateWidgets` migration?

If you have added it after running the migration, then you need to either run `bundle exec rake db:migrate:redo` or run `bundle exec rake db:migrate:rollback` and then `bundle exec rake db:migrate`. Essentially you need to ensure that this migration has created both the tables. You may need to add `STEP` parameter while running these tasks.

Refer to [Active Record Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried running `bundle exec rake db:migrate:redo` but I get this error message "SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users_widgets: DROP TABLE "users_widgets"C:in 'migrate'"

Comment: I am afraid that after running `rake db:reset` then `rake db:migrate` as suggested by jvillian in the Qs comments, I still get the `could not find table error` - any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

When you're confident that your migrations are correct yet you still have these problems, it can (sometimes) be due to the fact that previous, failed migrations have left the dB in a state that is hard to debug and/or correct.

In these instances, I often do:

```
$ rake db:drop          # completely removes the database
$ rake db:create        # creates a new, empty database
$ rake db:migrate       # builds your tables
$ rake db:test:prepare  # prepares your test database
```